# Analysis tool for Riak, like Cube or Graphite

Tags: analysis, aggregation, riak, graphite

Is there any analysis tool like [Graphite](http://graphite.wikidot.com/) or [Cube](http://square.github.com/cube/) based on Riak?

I'm basically looking for an aggregation framework I can use with Riak to do real-time analytics and data aggregations.

Answer (score 1):

pretty old question but [Druid](https://github.com/metamx/druid/wiki) may be a good fit.

This is how:

- Druid supports S3 as a "deep store" on which aggregates, inverted indices and all other stuff to do realtime olap queries are based
- The Riak CS storage API is S3-compatible.